# python: how to find not substring but subpicture?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, imagemagick

How to find not substring but subpicture? I need to find position of small image on the big image. Any ideas how to do that?

I mean: how to do it more rapidly then simple loop for pixels in gtk.gdk.Pixbuf?

Comment: How easily it can be done depends on what you are looking for. 

Is the object you are looking for consistent, like looking for boxes? Or is it more vague like 'find an animal'?

Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Could you please post (links to) samples of one of your images and to-be-matched subimages, please?

Comment: **Also, please do tell:** Is your sub-image in the same file format as the image? Does it have the same 'resolution'? Does it use the same color space?

Comment: Wow, the accepted answer is so off the track that I can't imagine how it got accepted. Hough transform, especially generalizations of it, is very far from being a fast algorithm. If the answers to @KurtPfeifle are all "yes", then all you need is a simple correlation between the subpicture you have, and the big image. The highest responses after the correlation are very likely to represent the center of your subpictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are algorithms for [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching). I studied image processing briefly and the only way I learned to do this was using [generalized Hough transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), which can be used to detect any shape you want. There may be other ways, but this one is definitely much faster, and much more robust, than iterating over all pixels.

Apparently, the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) package for Python has the Hough transform implemented. Sample code is [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Python). I never used PIL, but these links might be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) I spend whole hour and I could not understand how to enhance code from rosettacode to make it solve my issue. If you really good at this - can you help me with this please?

Comment: @scythargon: To help you further, it would help immensely to have a better idea of what kind of images we're talking about. See also Bill's comment, with which I agree -- your original question is somewhat vague. If you could edit it and add an example (just two links, one with the template and one with the main image), it would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you start describing your problem in relation to substring, I assume your subpicture is present in the larger picture (as is the case in the substring problem). To do this task you perform a correlation between the subpicture and the larger one. More specifically, you want a normalized cross-correlation between them, and the resulting global peaks indicates the best matches.

Here is a sample image, some subpicture taken from it, and the resulting correlated image.

[image] [image] [image]

Here is the global maximum (a single point) in the resulting correlation:

[image]

And here is the subpicture, centered in the global maximum, over the original image.

[image]

In Matlab this takes one line:

```
h = normxcorr2(g, f); % g is a subpicture from f.
```